# angular file upload not injected properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im kinda new in angular stuff, and want to learn more, basicly i need angular-file-upload to upload some images and use those images, to do that i started installong bower globally, then i went to the angular-file-upload page and got the bower install command, execute it, after that i attached the script to my index page like this:

```
    <script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
```

last i wanted to add the angular-file-upload to my app so i did this:

```
var app = angular.module('lojaApp', ['ui.router','angular-file-upload']);
```

why it gives me everytime a error with the angular-file-upload module ?:S

Comment: It seems that according to the GitHub documentation, it should be ''angularFileUpload', not 'angular-file-upload'. Try that and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

Inject it to your app like

```
var app = angular.module('lojaApp', ['ui.router','angularFileUpload']);
```

Answer (score 0):

### NG5 -File Upload

```
<p class="subhead">File Attachement</p>
<p>
  <strong>Upload file types: .xls</strong>
</p>
<div class="form-group" name="uploadBtn">
  <label class="btn btn-primary clear" aria-expanded="false">Upload
    <input type="file" [formControl]="document" (change)="uploadFile($event)" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
  </label>
</div>
```